# Is ansible compatible with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run small playbook over Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine and facing the issue while it gathers the facts.

```
PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/lsb_release -a", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/lsb_release': '/usr/bin/lsb_release'", "rc": 2}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/srini/VirtualEnv/image-mgmt/image-mgmtv3/linux_prepup_main.retry

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: Can you share playbook `yml` file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like lsb-release is not installed in ubuntu
Try to install it

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lsb-release
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually I was getting "/usr/bin/python" not found  issue before to this. Since Ubuntu comes with python3 by default, I symlink the python3.6 to /usr/bin/python and that is fixed. Now ansible requires python3 internally to execute it's script using python3.  lsb-release is already installed on the machine so I'm removing the old fixes and use ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 while executing the playbook. Thanks again...

Comment: Then please write this as answer and select it as correct one 
to make clear understanding of this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ansible is compatible with Ubuntu 18.04.

You have this error because you run your playbook on localhost instead of target server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around, I got the issue.